# Método onClick de DatePicker

Tags: android

Muestro un DatePicker de esta forma:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fecha "/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/LblFechaHacerReserva"
               />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnFechaHacerReserva"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Elegir Fecha"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

En la actividad:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
```

Y la clase DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private TextView lblFechaHacerReserva;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        c.set(year, month, day+7);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("APP", "OnClick en datepicker");
            }
        });
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        lblFechaHacerReserva = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.LblFechaHacerReserva);
        lblFechaHacerReserva.setText(String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));
    }
}
```

¿Por qué no funciona el método onClick? No me muestra nada por consola cuando hago click en mostrar fecha y elijo una.

Actualización:

Para que funcione añadir:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(
                year,
                month,
                day,
                new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Método onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es que no sirva me parece que intentas ver el mensaje en tu LogCat pero no se muestra, tu método `onClick()` únicamente imprime un mensaje de nivel "info" con el Tag "APP", revisa tengas tu filtro con "Info" o "Verbose", recuerda que también se puede filtrar por el texto "APP".

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("APP", "OnClick en datepicker");
            }
```

Dentro del LogCat cambia a nivel "Verbose" o si deseas ser más especifico "Info".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización**:

Una disculpa, no había notado que el listener era el incorrecto, se tiene que usar [**`OnDateChangedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html) y mediante el método que se implementa [**`onDateChanged()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html#onDateChanged(android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int)) puedes ver los cambios

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(
                year,
                month,
                day,
                new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys, no me muestra nada en el logcat, he filtrado como me has dicho y nada,  es como si el evento y el método onClick no se ejecutase.

Comment: En ocasiones ha sucedido que el LogCat deja de reportarme mensajes, te sugiero poner un "breakpoint" en la línea  Log.i("APP", "OnClick en datepicker"); ,  con eso aseguras que en verdad se este ejecutando, realizalo y me comentas!=)

Comment: Nada, no lo ejecuta :(

Comment: Ya he visto que sucede, mala nota por mi por omitir ver que listener usabas!

Comment: Gracias Elenasys por tu ayuda. Sólo he tenido que modificar un poco el código para que funcione, lo edito en mi primer mensaje.

Comment: @Red Si!, sinceramente no ví que usabas el listener incorrecto pero me da gusto hayas solucionado tu issue! =) saludos!